# How to access google spreadsheet data from my website?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to access google spreadsheet data from my website server side progrmming in `node.js`. I am able to embed spreadsheet in my webpage but not able to access its data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Script's [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service) to access the data in your spreadsheet, though some programming is required.